# In Google Sheets, is there a way to capture file information (Name/ID/URL) of an imported file with Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet into which users will repeatedly import CSVs manually (clearing previously imported data before a subsequent import). I'm hoping to find a way to capture the file name and id/url of the imported file when it is imported, to print the file name into a specified cell to identify which file is being worked with, then automatically changing the file name of the imported file when complete.

In searching, I've only been finding ways to automate the import or handling of CSVs after being uploaded to Drive, but not any ways to capture the file information of an imported file within the file it is being imported into. The spreadsheet does some querying/formatting for a related process, so it's doing more than just opening the raw data, but saved versions for each import are not necessary to maintain, so I'm not looking to generate a new file for every CSV.

Comment: have you checked [google app script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this with the Drive Activity API.  They have an Quick Start Example [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/quickstart/apps-script)
and I used it to create something I wanted which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64918766/7215091) and with this you can see that I was doing some work this morning where I wanted to scan the raw content of an email and I ended up moving the files into a raw content folder.  Here's part of today's Drive Activity Scan.

I had some difficulty with determining the query filter string so you may be able to provide some corrections to some of this work.  I'd appreciate knowing what you learn from it.  This is the first time I've messed with this API

[image]

And if you look closely you can see the folder id where I moved the file from and to and in column 4 it shows the file id.   I didn't really make much of an effort to make it real nice looking.  I was okay with just getting the info from the  JSON..

Comment: I don't have much to report back, unfortunately. For my needs, I didn't see the data I wanted in the Drive Activity output (csv file data when imported into a Google spreadsheet, not when it's uploaded to/moved within Drive).

I ended up going another route, as I couldn't seem to get the data I needed when using the built in Import option, I created my own csv data import script which allowed me to customize/simplify in other ways that are preferable for my project anyway.